# Use lambda/Proc in child class in ruby

Tags: ruby, lambda, proc

How can I use or reference a lambda that has been defined in base/super class?

Super class code

```
module Api
  class ApplicationSerializer
    include JSONAPI::Serializer

    # I Also tried it this way
    # serializer_for_proc = -> (object) { SerializerLookup.new.(object) }

    def serializer_for_proc
      -> (object) { SerializerLookup.new.(object) }
    end
  end
end
```

Child class code

```
module Api
  class AnswerSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
    attributes :values, :created_at, :updated_at, :usage

    belongs_to :question, serializer: serializer_for_proc # NameError (undefined local variable or method `serializer_for_proc' 
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think so because if I move the definition of the lambda to the sub class (AnswerSerializer) it will work fine with that syntax.

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with lambdas or procs. The OP does not understand how methods work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As presented, `serializer_for_proc` is an instance method of Api::ApplicationSerializer, but you're trying to invoke it directly on the class (or rather, directly on the subclass). In other words, all of the following fail for more-or-less the same reason:

```rb
belongs_to :question, serializer: serializer_for_proc
belongs_to :question, serializer: ApplicationSerializer.serializer_for_proc
belongs_to :question, serializer: AnswerSerializer.serializer_for_proc
```

You've never actually defined `ApplicationSerializer.serializer_for_proc`, you've defined what is traditionally written as `ApplicationSerializer#serializer_for_proc`, or in other words, `ApplicationSerailizer.new.serializer_for_proc`.

The quickest way to fix this would be to make the original method definition a class method:

```rb
module Api
  class ApplicationSerializer
    include JSONAPI::Serializer

    def self.serializer_for_proc
      -> (object) { SerializerLookup.new.(object) }
    end
  end
end
```

You wrote in a comment that it *did* work when you copied it into the AnswerSerializer file, but this is unlikely (basically impossible). What *would* work would be copying the `serializer_for_proc = -> (object) { SerializerLookup.new.(object) }` version into the AnswerSerializer file, because then `serializer_for_proc` isn't a method name at all, it's just a local variable within the `AnswerSerializer` file, same as `x = 5`. But that's not inheritable.

Another solution (although one I like significantly less) would be making `serializer_for_proc` a constant, e.g.:

```rb
# One file
module Api
  class ApplicationSerializer
    include JSONAPI::Serializer


    SERIALIZER_FOR_PROC = -> (object) { SerializerLookup.new.(object) }
  end
end

# Another file
module Api
  class AnswerSerializer < ApplicationSerializer
    attributes :values, :created_at, :updated_at, :usage

    belongs_to :question, serializer: SERIALIZER_FOR_PROC 
  end
end
```

That works, but I don't like to rely on this because inheritance-based constant lookup in Ruby has some [pretty weird edge cases](https://cirw.in/blog/constant-lookup.html). I'd personally just use `Api::ApplicationSerializer::SERIALIZER_FOR_PROC` if I wanted to use a constant.